# Determine the relative path of a package

Tags: luatex, xparse, paths

The general idea is that I can get the relative path of my project root by including the package mymacros.sty in my subprojects. I have the following setup:

- mymacros.sty
- myimg

  - figure.tikz

the content of mymacros.sty looks like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mymacros}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \projectabspath {}
{%
  \directlua{tex.print(file.pathpart(file.addsuffix(file.collapsepath("\@currname"),'sty')))}%
}
```

I'm extracting the relative path from the `\@currname` macro with lua.

When I call the macro in my file figure.tikz

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}

\usepackage{../mymacros}
\typeout{\projectabspath}

\begin{document}
absolute path: \projectabspath
\end{document}
```

I get an empty path. What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [quote David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124013/80496):

> The argument of \usepackage is a name not a file path. The fact that it sometimes works at all when passed a relative file path is just due to lack of error checking by the system. If the package does declare itself using \ProvidesPackage the use of such paths will generate a warning that the name is incorrect.

Let's ignore that for a second and see why your code does not work:

You get the value of `\@currname` at the point the macro is expanded, which is in the middle of your document. There is no current package at that point, so `\@currname` is empty.

To fix this you have to expand `\projectabspath` while reading the package. You can use `\edef` to archive this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mymacros}

\edef \projectabspath
{%
  \directlua{tex.print(file.pathpart(file.collapsepath("\@currname", true)))}%
}
```

or define the macro directly from Lua:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mymacros}

\directlua{
  token.set_macro('projectabspath', file.pathpart(file.collapsepath(token.scan_string(), true)))
}\@currname
```

Note that I added `, true` to collapsepath, otherwise the returned path is not absolute.

In general LuaTeX provides a more reliable way to get the path of the current file that analyzing `\@currname`: Use `status.filename`.

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mymacros}

\directlua{
  token.set_macro('projectabspath', file.pathpart(file.collapsepath(status.filename, true)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly fine! What would be the preferred way to call a package from a top folder?

Comment: You could [add the top folder to `\input@path`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79058/can-a-default-path-be-set-globally-for-input-akin-to-graphicspath/79060). After that `\usepackage{mymacros}` would find it.

Comment: Why is it not working when I use `lfs.currentdir()` instead of `\@currname` to determine the path of mymacros.sty?

Comment: @Reza `lfs.currentdir()` returns the current working directory of the TeX process. TeX never changes the working directory during a run, so `lfs.currentdir()` always gives the directory TeX was called from. Normally this is the directory of your main document.