# How do I find out which paths my (La)TeX installation checks looking for packages (on a Linux system)?

Tags: packages, installing

I know that I can check from where one particular package would be called, using

```
kpsewhich <packagename>.sty
```

and that if I want a custom package, I usually have to put it in the same folder as my document.

I assume that similar to a $PATH, LaTeX checks a list of paths in an attempt to find my package.

**Which paths are those? In what order are they checked? If this is system-specific, how can I find out the configuration for my system?**

Related questions:

- [How can I properly resolve relative paths in `\usepackage`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-properly-resolve-relative-paths-in-usepackage), the answers to which contain some paths that 
  LaTeX apparently checks.
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1141/188892 mentions

```
>    /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf
>    /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist
>    /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
>
> as well as other directories.
```

(Neither of those lists is complete).

Comment: texlive 2009?? really? kpsewhich --help will you give a lot of options. texdoc kpathsea will open the documentation. The pathes themselves are in the `texmf.cnf`.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be an 'XY' question: is there some broader reason you are asking?

Comment: `kpsewhich` uses a file called `ls-R` (inside the `texmf-dist` folder) which contains a list of known files and their location inside the texmf tree. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @JosephWright: I was seeking to broaden my understanding of how LaTeX works in general; the use case that prompted the question was that I wanted to move a package file to a subfolder of a git repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call

```
kpsewhich -var-brace-value=TEXINPUTS
```

and you get (reformatted adding a line break after `:`):

```
.:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex/kpsewhich//:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex/kpsewhich//:
<userhome>/texmf/tex/kpsewhich//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/kpsewhich//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex/kpsewhich//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex/kpsewhich//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/kpsewhich//:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex/generic//:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex/generic//:
<userhome>/texmf/tex/generic//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex/generic//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex/generic//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic//:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex/latex//:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex/latex//:
<userhome>/texmf/tex/latex//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex/latex//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex/latex//:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex//:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex///:
<userhome>/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex///:
<userhome>/texmf/tex///:
!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex///:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config/tex///:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/tex///:
!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex///
```

I just masked the path to my home dir; in your case you can get `<userhome>/.texlive` (this is distribution dependent). A trailing `//` or `///` means that the directory is searched recursively. A leading `!!` means that the (recursive) search is done by looking in a `ls-R` file generated by `maketexlsr`. Otherwise the (recursive) search is performed at runtime.

The various paths are searched in the specified order, a match will stop the search.

The first `.` represents the working directory when the TeX engine is called from.