# StrSubstitute Missing Number Treated as 0 when Inputing \_

Tags: errors, xstring, missing

I'm having trouble tracking down an error that looks like a missing input error, but is occurring in a strange place. I'm trying to take a detokenized string (actually a macro in my actual doc) with an underscore in it and replace the detokenized underscore with a "cancelled" underscore (ie: `\_`). I pass the result to `\Result` and then attempt to print it to check if it worked. It doesn't. In fact the error is for line 13 rather than line 9 where the initial macro is.

If, however, I replace the `\_` with any other non-control character then I receive no errors. Can anyone explain why I am having this error and how to fix it?

Error:

```
  1 Tutorials/Example1/Example1.tex|13 error| Missing number, treated as zero.                     
  2 Tutorials/Example1/Example1.tex|13 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}   % EDIT: From answer, minimal shouldn't be used.

\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

%%% Set a fake return.
\def\theabsdir{\detokenize{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}}

\StrSubstitute[0]{\theabsdir}{\detokenize{_}}{\_}[\Result]      % LINE 9

\begin{document}
Before: \theabsdir\\
After: \Result                                                 % LINE 13
\end{document}
```

This is the intended usage, but it doesn't work for a variety of reasons. Essentially pseudocode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

% Determine path of current file
\getabspath{Example.tex} % this provides \theabsdir, the file's directory.

% Delete folders up to the project's root directory.
\StrDel{\theabsdir}{path/to/project_root/}[\ProjectRoot]

% Add the location of custom packages
\def\StylePath{\ProjectRoot style_name}

% Load custom package
\usepackage[options]{\StylePath}

%%% End Preamble
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

First, you shouldn't use the `minimal` class; it isn't intended for end-users, only for specific tests by LaTeX developers.

Second, your problem goes away if you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your document. `T1` being more modern than `OT1`, this may be what you want to do.

The problem when using `OT1` here is due to the fact that `\_` doesn't stay unchanged<sup>1</sup> when you use it inside `\edef`, and according to the `xstring` documentation, this happens under the hood when you call `\StrSubstitute` in the default régime of `\fullexpandarg` (see *Expansion of arguments* in the `xstring` documentation).

I suspect this documentation doesn't tell the whole truth, though, otherwise the following ought to work even in `OT1`:

```latex
\StrSubstitute[0]{\theabsdir}{\detokenize{_}}{\noexpand\_}[\Result]
```

as well as

```latex
\StrSubstitute[0]{\theabsdir}{\detokenize{_}}{\unexpanded{\_}}[\Result]
```

You can convince yourself that `\_` in `OT1` encoding doesn't survive an `\edef` with the following test document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\edef\x{\_}
\x
\end{document}
```

which prints:

```latex
./test.tex:5: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.5 \end{document}
```

With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, it works well.

One way to avoid the error in `OT1` while keeping using `xstring` is to wrap `\_` inside a `\protected` macro—such macros never ever get expanded by `\edef`, `\write`, etc.:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\theabsdir{\detokenize{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}}

\protected\def\zzz{\_}
\StrSubstitute[0]{\theabsdir}{\detokenize{_}}{\zzz}[\Result]

\begin{document}
Before: \theabsdir\par
After: \Result
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is probably not what you were hoping for. A reliable way to solve this problem is to use `expl3` functions. I propose to use slightly different input, I think it will be more useful for your real-world use cases. The input with the following code can be either:

```latex
% Note: no \detokenize here
\def\theabsdir{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}
...
\sanitizeMacro{\theabsdir}{\Result}
```

or

```latex
\sanitizeString{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}{\Result}
```

(but I can handle your `\def\theabsdir{\detokenize{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}}` if you really prefer).

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% Probably a good idea to load this, even if it works without.
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \lagix_sanitize:nN #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } % \tl_to_str:n is \detokenize
    \tl_replace_all:Nxn \l_tmpa_tl { \char_generate:nn { `_ } { 12 } } { \_ }
    % Alternative to the previous line:
    % \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cD\_ } { \c{_} } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_set_eq:NN #2 \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lagix_sanitize:nN { V }
% Not needed if you use the \regex_replace_all:nnN way above:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nx }

\NewDocumentCommand \sanitizeString { m m }
  {
    \lagix_sanitize:nN {#1} #2
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \sanitizeMacro { m m }
  {
    \lagix_sanitize:VN #1 #2
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Note: no \detokenize here
\def\theabsdir{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}

\begin{document}

\sanitizeMacro{\theabsdir}{\Resulti}
\sanitizeString{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}{\Resultii}

Before: \detokenize{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}\par
After: \Resulti, \Resultii.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Footnote**

1. Various tests are performed at the time of the `\edef` and the results of these tests become hardcoded in the expansion recorded by `\edef`, since one of the branches is discarded for each test (assuming the test itself can be performed, which is not necessarily the case when expanding too early!).

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! Both the `T1` and the `sanitizeMacro` are giving me good results printing, but they aren't giving me good results for utilization in other macros - specifically in `StrSubstitute` and `usepackage`. I use the currfile to get `theabsdir` and so I can get around the StrSubstitute by subbing before sanitizing, but `usepackage` gives me a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error. Any hints as to how I might get around this issue? This may be one of those "post a new question" scenarios.

Comment: I modified the initial question in case it provides clarity about how I am using the final string.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid it can't work this way. `\usepackage` expects a package *name*—[providing a path is an error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-properly-resolve-relative-paths-in-usepackage). Moreover, you aren't even passing a path in your new pseudo-code, you are passing a macro (there is no rule saying that macros have to expand all their arguments—rule which would need to be precised, BTW). And yes, this is a different question.

Comment: Ok, so this is not the right way to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: It appears the cs method doesn't work for `input` either. Are these methods only usable for actual text and can't be used in other macros?

Comment: `\_` is a command for **typesetting** an underscore. When you pass a file name containing underscores to `\input`, these underscores are *not going to be typeset.* You need to pass underscore *character tokens* in this case (to `\input`), as produced for instance when expanding `\string_`. Related: [\ForEach fails with underscores](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456726/73317) and [How to create sections and input file provided a different file exists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525020/73317).

Comment: In other words, you shouldn't need to transform the file path for `\input`. Just use a copy of the unmodified path, for instance made with `\let`. The result of `\detokenize` on the path should be okay, too.

Comment: Oh right, of course. I should have known that. Any hint on how to track the values of strings with underscores then? I was printing this to check if their values were correct, but given that it's typesetting vs a character token then printing won't do me any good.

Comment: And yeah, I just got it working even with detokenized characters... I just couldn't print it! Failure to compile made me think it was broken, but I suppose it actually meant that the underscores carried through.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `xstring` will perform “all the way expansion” to the arguments to `\StrSubstitute` and `\_` doesn't survive this process.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

%%% Set a fake return.
\def\theabsdir{\detokenize{/Users/Me/Example_with_underscore}}

\StrSubstitute[0]{\theabsdir}{\detokenize{_}}{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\_}[\Result]

\begin{document}

Before: \theabsdir

After: \Result

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you know to use exactly three `\noexpand` commands? I would think that only one would be needed.

Comment: @Lagix The argument is subject to full expansion twice.